# PaperJS: Join multiple path objects to create a single path object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, canvas, paperjs

Lets say I have multiple path objects of various shapes and sizes, that intersect with one another, like those in the `[Hit Testing example][1]`. Assuming I have a few of them selected at the same time, how could I join them together into a single path element, eliminating the overlapping path points, to create a new shape. For the sake of simplicity, let's apply the fill from the topmost shape.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have a look at paper.js `unite()` method as described here [Merging two bezier-based shapes into one to create a new outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71077189/merging-two-bezier-based-shapes-into-one-to-create-a-new-outline/)

Comment: That actually solves my issue, I couldn't find anything on uniting paths and this looks like the way to go, thank you.